# Pine Script TradingView Alert Automation

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have zero experience with coding. I am using a publicly available strategy (Pine Script v4) on TradingView and I want to connect it to my 3Commas bot using TradingView's custom signals.

What I need to do is make the bot call for a long position when the price crosses/touches any of the defined support or resistance levels AND closes above the lines, and vice versa for a short position, with a trailing take profit/stop loss.
I'm stuck because I am not able to call the function of the same.
if possible, I would also like to add another indicator for more precision in the future along with this.

```
enter code here
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, if you have zero coding experience, you should definitely get help from a professional. Check out [this](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000601677-where-can-i-find-a-reliable-pine-programmer-to-hire/) list provided by Tradingview.

Comment: Don't worry thanks, i coded it myself last night. The issue was between the different version syntaxes:)